# SharePoint 2013 Wiki Search

Tags: 2013, search, wiki

I've set up Enterprise Wiki Site Collection and within I made several subsites (all of them are made as Enterprise Wikis).

When I search something from root web, I can see data in all subsites. However, when I search for something within subsite I can only see items which are tied to that subsite.
What I'd like is to have the same behavior on the all search boxes within this wiki Site Collection. In other words, no matter on which subsite the user is, he can always query the whole site collection.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please check my answer in the following post:
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/108369/search-multiple-site-collections/108517#108517
You can apply this. It works..Best of luck!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about just setting up the Enterprise Search Centre and changing the 'Which search results page should queries be sent to?' property on your sites?

You can also set this at the root and have your subsites inherit this property.

This is what the Search Centre was made for: Searching across all content.